# Find common and unique numbers and put them in a new integer vector in R

Tags: r

I have 2 integer vectors named `k` and `r`. I would like to create a new vector which will contain numbers that are within both + unique numbers for both of them.
See example below:

`k`:

```
1 4 8 9 10
```

`r`:

```
1 10 4 12 14
```

The desired result:

```
1 4 8 9 10 12 14
```

Comment: `sort(union(k, r))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are searching for `union(k,r)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `unique` with `sort`

```
sort(unique(c(r, k)))
#[1]  1  4  8  9 10 12 14
```

#### data

```
k <- c(1, 4, 8, 9, 10)
r <- c(1, 10, 4, 12, 14)
```